# log4j:ERROR A "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender" object is not assignable to a "org.apache.log4j.Appender" variable

Tags: java, exception, logging, log4j, gradle

I am making a web app using gradle. I used log4j in this app. When I build the project I am getting error...

- log4j:ERROR A "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender" object is not assignable to a "org.apache.log4j.Appender" variable.
- log4j:ERROR The class "org.apache.log4j.Appender" was loaded by
- log4j:ERROR [org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader@16a40b2] whereas object of type
- log4j:ERROR "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender" was loaded by [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5e3a78ad].
- log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "stdout".

I still did not find a good answer. And I forgot to say, My project build correctly and show log massages correctly. It doesn't work only on test classes.

Comment: The `ConsoleAppender` class is somehow getting loaded by a classloader from PowerMock and not correctly linked to the base `Appender` type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding this annotation works for me.

```
@PowerMockIgnore("org.apache.log4j.*")
```

Comment: But you are suppressing these error messages not fixing them.

Answer (score 6):

Your classpath contains 2 copies of log4j library. Exclude one and try again.

Comment: I just have used log4j-1.2.17 , slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5 with slf4j-api-1.7.5. And slf4j is facade.

Comment: how to check whether I have 2 copies or not? and how to fix ? Should I delete one?

Comment: @YestayMuratov by analyzing your classpath, it depends on the type of your application: either it web app deployed to application server, or any type of desktop/console app. You would have to delete one, but it depends on compatibility of these libraries. Due to semantic versioning if major version of these libraries differ, your code could be incompatible with library version that came to your classpath from outside.

Answer (score 3):

There is a Clear answer [here](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockPolicies). :D

When we have a final method and slf4j loggers in our classes. We have to use powermock in our test class. Because of this we have to use @MockPolicy(Slf4jMockPolicy.class) with particuler imports at the test class which we used Powermock.

Comment: The OP doesn't say that they are using slf4j. The answer posted by @ToYonos is more appropriate.